# no 'DATA' attribute in request in my view.py

Tags: javascript, django

i'm trying to pass data with js in `function UpdateUserOrder`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.update-cart').forEach(item =>{
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
            var productId = item.dataset.product
            var action = item.dataset.action
            if(user === 'AnonymousUser'){
                console.log('not logged in')
            }else{
                UpdateUserOrder(productId, action)
            }
        })
    })
})

function UpdateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log('user logged in')

    var url = 'add_to_cart/'

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId,'action':action})
    })
    .then((response) =>{
        return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) =>{
        console.log('data', data)
    })
}
```

```html
{% for product in products %}
    <div>
        <label id="title-label" for="title">Title</label>
        <p id="title">{{ product.title }}</p>
        <label id="author-label" for="author">Author</label>
        <p id="author">{{ product.author }}</p>
        <label for="user">Seller</label>
        <p id="user">{{ product.user }}</p>
        <p><img src="{{ product.image }}" alt="none"></p>
        <a id="link" href="{% url 'market_detail' product.id %}">Details</a>
        <button data-product="{{ product.id }}" data-action="add" class="update-cart">add</button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.filter(sold=False)
    context = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'market/home.html', context)


def add_to_cart(request):
    data = json.loads(request.DATA)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('action:', action, 'productId:', productId)
    return JsonResponse('item was added', safe=False)
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', BookDetailView.as_view(), name='market_detail'),
    path('search/', book_search, name='book_search'),
    path('add_to_cart/', add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
    ]
```

[the error i'm getting in my console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SleR0.png)

and my terminal in pycharm is saying this:

> AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: To know in which key under request your data exists, try printing request.__dict__. Data mostly received in request.POST or request.GET. Try printing them as well

Comment: @VineetYadav thanks i got it through request.body attribute :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the data through the request body (`body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId,'action':action})`), which means you have to access it in `views.py`:

```py
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

Also, you can always check the attributes of an object with the [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) built-in.